# Android application with changeable skin

Tags: android, themes, skin

I would like to give user option to change application's skin or theme. Let's say downloadable skin or built-in number of skins. Are there any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Downloadable would be really hard, because you want to use resources that are bundled and ID's generated. A number of built in is possible. Go away and try it. Come back when your stuck

Comment: Check this out : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html